# if statement within For loop - logic error

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, logic

Can someone help me figure out why this code is not returning False for ‘Instachat :stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye:’ and ‘Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite’? They contain characters (emoji and TM respectively ) whose unicodes are greater than 127, so technically, it should return False for both of them.

I don't understand why the else clause doesn't work here.

```
# My Code (logic doesn't seem to work)

def is_english(string):

    for character in string:
       if ord(character) > 127:
       return False

       else:
       return True

print(is_english(‘Instagram’))

print(is_english(‘爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播’))

print(is_english(‘Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite’))

print(is_english(‘Instachat :stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye:’))

#Solution Code (works but I don't understand why)

def is_english(string):

    for character in string:
        if ord(character) > 127:
            return False

    return True
```

The following should be the expected output for MY CODE:
True
False
False
False

However, the actual output is:
True
False
True 
True

Comment: You seem to have some indentation errors.

Comment: You return after the first iteration of your loop and never look at the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to change letters code range (e.g., like next):

```
def is_english(s):
    for c in s.lower():
        if ord('a') > ord(c) or ord(c) > ord('z'):
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function:

```
def is_english(string):
    for character in string:
        if ord(character) > 127:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

is not working as expected because you return the result (either `True` or `False`) based only on the first `character` in `string`. You have to move the `return True` statement outside the `for` loop, just like in the second method you provided:

```
def is_english(string):
    for character in string:
        if ord(character) > 127:
            return False
    return True
```

This way you check every `character` against the given condition until one of the `character`s is found to be Non-English or until all `character`s have been checked. If neither was Non-English, then you can return `True`.

Comment: yes! you're right. Thank you so much jsamol!! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question you have to try in this way:

```
# The Code

def is_english(string):
    for character in string:
        if ord(character) > 127:
            return False #if character is major than 127
        else:
            return True #if character is minor than 127

print(is_english('Instagram'))

print(is_english('爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播'))

print(is_english('Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite'))

print(is_english('Instachat :stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye:'))
```

> The Output is: True False True True

The indentation is incorrect and then your code doesn't work.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only checking the first letter only and returning trye/false.